# Shows OutOfBoundsException for index 3 even when array list shows Size 5

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
int q, k;
String query, s;
q = input.nextInt();

for (k = 0; k < q+1; k++) {
    query = input.nextLine();
    batch.getResult().add_res(query);
    s = (batch.getResult().get_res(k));
    //System.out.println(s);
    String[] ss = s.split(" ");
    for(int l=0;l<ss.length;l++) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", ss[l]);
    }
    System.out.println(ss.length);
    System.out.printf("%s \n",ss[3]);
    System.out.println();        
}
```

Here the code prints out the contents of the arrayList properly also return `ss.length = 5`, but when I print `ss[3]` it shows and `OutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: What is the value of `s` when the failure occurs?

Comment: Then it should fail in the `for` loop also

Comment: Could you  post your exception trace as well?

Comment: When I add the print statement  -> System.out.printf("%s \n",ss[3]); this one , it just prints 1 nothing is printed in the for loop

Comment: Check the following: what's in `s`, what's in `ss` and is the data inside them what you expect them to be, or does it need some tweaking. If you find those things out, maybe you'll find the answer. If not, please provide the data, so we can help out.

Comment: can you write here, what you are getting in 's'

Comment: I know it may be a little much to ask if you’re a beginner, but I am asking anyway: A [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org), please? Because (1) preparing that is likely to lead you to your bug (2) when we have one, we can help you a whole lot better.

Comment: By the way. You should not use variable names which are misleading. This one looks like you would be using 1 as numeric constant: `System.out.printf("%s ", ss[l]);` on first sight on some charsets.